# Run Fred's ImageMagick scripts with PHP Imagick in Windows environment

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm fairly new to ImageMagick and I recently I discovered this wonderful tutorial resource called **Fred's ImageMagick Scripts**

However, I'm wondering how o use these scripts with PHP Imagick extension on a Windows environment (WAMP).

For instance this is a Fred's Script for correction gamma of an image.

```
USAGE: autogamma [-c colormode] infile outfile
USAGE: autogamma [-h or -help]

-c .... colormode ..... colorspace/channel to use to compute 
....................... gamma statistics; choices are: gray, 
....................... intensity, luminance, lightness, brightness, 
....................... average, magnitude, rgb; default=luminance 
-m .... midrange ...... midrange value from which to compute gamma; 
....................... 0<float<1; default=0.5
```

This is the only code available in **Fred's Script** page.

Now, here I'm creating a new Imagick object and reading the particular image I'm going to edit with **Fred's script**.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage( $imagePath );
```

So, from hereafter, how to link these two scripts ? How to add that Fred's script to my Imagick object ?

Is there any additional software or library that needs to be installed ? Or a file that needs to be imported ?

## Update

```
$result = chmod("2colorthresh", 0777); 
echo $result;

$result2 = exec("2colorthresh -help"); 
echo $result2;
```

For the first echo, I get 1. as I think TRUE.

But for the second echo, I get nothing.

Comment: Try changing exec to system in $result2

Comment: @Bonzo Still not getting anything :(

Answer (score 3):

You can not / do not need to run Freds scripts in Imagemagick or Imagick as they are stand alone bash scripts.

You will probably need to install Cygwin or similar as some of the Linux type functions are not available in a windows localhost environment.

If you do get everything setup to run on windows and want to use php you whould first need to CHMOD the script to 777 or whatever you need to do to the permissions and then use some code like this:

```
exec("/FULL PATH TO/script.sh input.png output.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed Cygwin and now I can use some of the linux commands like `ls`, `pwd`, `cd` in windows terminal. However, for the PHP script, I created, still getting no effect.  I updated the question with more details. Please kindly check that.

Comment: See my homepage at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php for reference to usage with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

My scripts do not run in Imagick. You can run them using PHP exec().

Try something like:

```
<?php
exec("bash 2colorthresh logo: logo.gif 2>&1",$out,$returnval);
foreach($out as $text)
{echo "$text<br>";}
?>
```

If that fails, provide the full path to 2colorthresh and your images as needed. If your downloaded file has .sh appended, then either rename it or use 2colorthresh.sh in the command.